# Sort different fields by the label in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get a chaotic array of data from the backend. The REF and LOT labels can be in different indexes, I need them to always be 1 and 2 (REF and LOT) on the frontend. How can I check labels and sort?

Ver1:

```
array1 = [
    { label: 'GT', placeholder: null, value: '001111' },
    { label: 'Date', placeholder: null, value: '01/01/2000' },
    { label: 'LOT', placeholder: null, value: '84739' },
    { label: 'REF', placeholder: null, value: '11111' },
    { label: 'Company', placeholder: null, value: 'Company' },
  ];
```

Ver2:

```
array2 = [
    { label: 'GT', placeholder: null, value: '001111' },
    { label: 'LOT', placeholder: null, value: '84739' },
    { label: 'Date', placeholder: null, value: '01/01/2000' },
    { label: 'Company', placeholder: null, value: 'Company' },
    { label: 'REF', placeholder: null, value: '11111' },
  ];
```

Result:

```
[
    { label: 'REF', placeholder: null, value: '11111' },
    { label: 'LOT', placeholder: null, value: '84739' },
    { label: 'GT', placeholder: null, value: '001111' },
    { label: 'Date', placeholder: null, value: '01/01/2000' },
    { label: 'Company', placeholder: null, value: 'Company' },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use compare function

```
let array1 = [
        { label: 'GT', placeholder: null, value: '001111' },
        { label: 'Date', placeholder: null, value: '01/01/2000' },
        { label: 'LOT', placeholder: null, value: '84739' },
        { label: 'REF', placeholder: null, value: '11111' },
        { label: 'Company', placeholder: null, value: 'Company' },
    ];

    array1.sort((firstEl, secondEl) => {
        if (secondEl.label === "REF") {
            return 1;
        } else if (secondEl.label === "LOT") {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to re-order simply enough, creating an orderArrayByLabels function that will do the desired sorting.

```js
array1 = [
    { label: 'GT', placeholder: null, value: '001111' },
    { label: 'Date', placeholder: null, value: '01/01/2000' },
    { label: 'LOT', placeholder: null, value: '84739' },
    { label: 'REF', placeholder: null, value: '11111' },
    { label: 'Company', placeholder: null, value: 'Company' },
  ];
     
array2 = [
    { label: 'GT', placeholder: null, value: '001111' },
    { label: 'LOT', placeholder: null, value: '84739' },
    { label: 'Date', placeholder: null, value: '01/01/2000' },
    { label: 'Company', placeholder: null, value: 'Company' },
    { label: 'REF', placeholder: null, value: '11111' },
];

function orderArrayByLabels(arr, labelOrder) {
   // Start with only the elements in labelOrder array
   let result = labelOrder.map(label => array1.find(el => el.label === label));
   // Finish with only the elements _not_ in labelOrder array
   return result.concat(arr.filter(el => !labelOrder.includes(el.label)));
}


console.log("Array1:", orderArrayByLabels(array1, ['REF', 'LOT']))
console.log("Array2:", orderArrayByLabels(array2, ['REF', 'LOT']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take an object of order and for missing value move them to end by assigning a large value.

```js
const array = [ { label: 'GT', placeholder: null, value: '001111' }, { label: 'LOT', placeholder: null, value: '84739' }, { label: 'Date', placeholder: null, value: '01/01/2000' }, { label: 'Company', placeholder: null, value: 'Company' }, { label: 'REF', placeholder: null, value: '11111' }, ],
    sortOrder = ['REF', 'LOT'],
    order = Object.fromEntries(sortOrder.map((k, i) => [k, i + 1]));
    
array.sort((a, b) => (order[a.label] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[b.label] || Number.MAX_VALUE) );

console.log(array);
```